# How to make "Eclipse for Java developers" include Javascript capabilities?

Tags: eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse, and have the following question:

I would like to use Eclipse to program java and javascript. I went to eclipse.org and downloaded "Eclipse for Java Developers", though there was also an option to download "Eclipse for JavaScript developers".

So the question is: How do I extend my "Eclipse for Java Developers" to include the JavaScript capabilities included in "Eclipse for JavaScript developers" ?

Is that even possible ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install Eclipse's WTP (Web Tools Platform) using the update site featured on the following page: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/.

To do this, you should:
1) Open up the software updates dialog (Help -> Install New Software...);
2) Click the 'Add' button;
3) Enter a suitable name (WTP), and the aforementioned URL;
4) Select whichever releases of WTP you would like to install;
5) Press 'Next' and follow the rest of the instructons.

(Note: The WTP update site may already be in the list of available sites in the Available Software dialog, so you should probably check before installing from scratch.)

Comment: NOTE: for the most recent updates, for Helios, use http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios

Comment: For Eclipse Neon.3, I went to Help/Eclipse Marketplace and searched for WTP, which let me install Eclipse Web Developer Tools, which includes the HTML, CSS, XML and JSON Editors, and JavaScript Developer Tools from the Eclipse Web Tools Platform project.

Answer (score 0):

welp's answer is the best approach.

You can overlay an Eclipse download over another Eclipse download.  I do this to get the Java EE Eclipse and the source code for Eclipse.

You answer "No for all" when your unzip program asks you if you want to overlay files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also start from [Enide](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enide-eclipse-nodejs-ide) and install using update site, install button or p2f file.

Any plugin that depends on JSDT (e.g. Nodeclipse, JSDT-EXTJS, JSDT-jQuery, AngularJS-Eclipse) will be installed together with JSDT.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this question is old but there are some news regarding the JavaScript (or let's say the direct web development in general) development in eclipse:

http://eclipse.org/orion/